# See SSRS subscriptions via SSL query? Query to generate parameters.

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, subscription

I am a setting up a test SSRS server to work "just like production, just a little different".  I got the reports, the tempDB, and all the datasets working.

Need help on subscriptions. 
Production server has a small number of subscriptions, and I can see them through the browser UI.  However, it doesn't show where it pushes the report files.

> Update: found a way to see where the files are dropped, in the
>   Subscription Manager tool.  Still looking for how the parameters are
>   generated when the report is run through subscription. There is one
>   parameter that doesn't have a default and requires input when report
>   is run manually.

Is where a way to see the subscription information by running a SQL query(-ies)? 
Is it possible to set up subscriptions by inserting data into tables directly, without dealing with the UI?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by " it doesn't show where it pushes the report files.". Normally when you edit a subscription that generates a file it will show the path that it will download to (assuming that it isn't being emailed).

Comment: @DeanOC The step 4 page just says "get the value from the database". I added the screenshot to the question.  Where in the database can I find it? Looking for all values on that page (other than the password).

Answer (score 1):

You are running data driven subscriptions based on the pictures you have posted. There will not be hardcoded file paths stored in this case. You will need to review the data driven query that produces the results at run time and compare that between your two environments. Check the columns in `ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions` for the query that will be executed at run time. For each row returned in this query a report will be delivered (10 rows, 10 reports, each with their own custom attributes based on the mapping you provided in the picture).

I would not recommend direct inserts into `ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions`. Things will likely not work as you want them to. SSRS creates a number of other items when you create a subscription via the UI (one large component is a SQL Agent job).

You can explore creating subscriptions via the SSRS API. It’s fairly easy to integrate with C#.

Comment: There are 4 columns in ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions with XML data:
ExtensionSettings, MatchData, Parameters,  and DataSettings.  ExtensionSettings seems like the right place, but doesn't include the actual values, only types. 
Any other ideas on where to look? 

thank you!

Comment: The data is inside one of those columns. You can copy the XML out into a new query window and review it. If you have the subscriptions set to save to a file share, the path to the file share will be present in one of those columns. I would say it would be either ExtensionSettings or DataSettings.

Comment: Are you able to post the contents of the ExtensionSettings XML? You can redact anything that may be sensitive.

Comment: OH - OKAY!. I see what is going on (didn't review the pictures on my mobile device but did when I got back to a PC). You have a data driven subscription running. So you are only going to see the parameters - not the values as they are returned at run time. In the subscription table you can find the query used for the "data driven" part and review that. Effectively you will be comparing tables/views between PROD and DEV/TEST now.

Comment: which column in subscription table would have the query for the "data driven" part?

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head. Query `ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions` and look at the columns. Copy the XML data out to a new query window, notepad, etc. and review the data inside the XML. You should easily be able to find the data driven query.

Comment: Just got access to a ReportServer. Check `ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions.DataSettings` column. There will be an XML element inside of it called `<CommandText>` which will contain the query of the data driven subscription.

Comment: thank you! I figured out how to restructure the query for the test server.